# BigQuery pricing, is it in Terabyte or Tebibyte?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

So 1TB costs 5$,

But is it TB meaning Terabyte (so 10^12) or Tebibyte (2^40). If I trsut the notation it is Terabyte so

I'm asking because I have - the total_bytes_billed (in bytes) and want to convert to dollars.

Comment: It's [tebibyte](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#:~:text=bytes.-,this%20unit%20of%20measurement%20is%20also%20known%20as%20a%20gibibyte%20(gib).%20similarly%2C%201%20tb%20is%20240%20bytes%20(1%2C024%20gb).,-If).

Comment: Thx for your reply. do you have any reference ?

Comment: Does the link in my comment not answer your question?

Comment: My bad, the link above was about storage pricing. [This link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#:~:text=the%20size%20of%20your%20stored%20data%2C%20and%20the%20size%20of%20the%20data%20processed%20by%20your%20queries%20is%20calculated%20in%20gigabytes%20(gb)%2C%20where%201%20gb%20is%20230%20bytes) shows the detail when reading the data. It's gibibyte/tebibyte too.

Comment: You rock @Marth ! The second link is the one. Don’t hesitate to add it in the answer so I can accept it. Thx again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#:%7E:text=the%20size%20of%20your%20stored%20data%2C%20and%20the%20size%20of%20the%20data%20processed%20by%20your%20queries%20is%20calculated%20in%20gigabytes%20(gb)%2C%20where%201%20gb%20is%20230%20bytes.%20this%20unit%20of%20measurement%20is%20also%20known%20as%20a%20gibibyte%20(gib).%20similarly%2C%201%20tb%20is%20240%20bytes%20(1%2C024%20gb).), the units are gibibyte/tebibyte. The formulation is a bit confusing though, using both "gigabyte" and "gibibyte" for the same value (2^30):

> **Data size calculation**
>
> When you load data into BigQuery or query the data, you're charged according to the data size. Data size is calculated based on the size of each column's data type.
>
> The size of your stored data, and the size of the data processed by your queries is calculated in gigabytes (GB), where 1 GB is 2^30 bytes. This unit of measurement is also known as a gibibyte (GiB). Similarly, 1 TB is 2^40 bytes (1,024 GB).

---

Note that "$5/TB" is only valid in some regions. For instance, when using europe-west1 the cost is $6/TB.
[The documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#on_demand_pricing) has a table listing all values per regions.